# Creative logo creation with a word

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo, camera

I have a local business of photography in Chennai India. 
The name is "Khaleel Photography"
I like to create a logo for my portfolio representing the word "Khaleel" and also indicates camera in it.

am trying it out in Photoshop. am not getting any good idea. If any logo designer or experts can give me a idea to create such. any suggestions or design or outline or mock up are welcomed and highly appreciated.TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Cou can look for inpiration online, if you want to do it by yourself.

---

- http://logopond.com/search/?search=photography
- http://abduzeedo.com/logo-design-cameras
- http://abduzeedo.com/logo-design-cameras-part-2-0
- http://www.pinterest.com/explore/camera-logo
- http://inspirationfeed.com/inspiration/logo-inspiration/51-clever-camera-and-photography-logo-designs
- http://designmodo.com/photography-logo/

---

If you realize you can't make it work by yourself without just copying the logos you like, hire a designer to do a personalized logo design for you.